# Calculating Treversal Tree items level

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I have a database that has category names. The columns are `ID | CategoryName | ParentID`. I'm using `row_array()` from the CodeIgniter model, and I want to add a level key to that row array. I have a helper function that recursively calculates all category levels. I wrote that helper function in the following code segment:

```
function treegenerate($arrs, $parent_id=0, $level=0) {
    foreach($arrs as $arr){
        if($arr["CategoryParent"]!=0){
            $level+=1;
        }
        $arr["Level"] = $level;
        treegenerate($arrs,$arr["CategoryParent"],$level);
    }
    return $arrs;
}
```

But it gives the error: "Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 523800 bytes)". How can I fix that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just some thoughts without knowing your code:

- Is it possible to add the level keys starting from the trunk? Might save you some repetition.
- Can you move the foreach outside of treegenerate?

Like:

```
function treegenerate($arr,$level=0) {
        if($arr["CategoryParent"]!=0){
           $level +=1;
        }
        else return $level; 

    }
    treegenerate($arr["CategoryParent"],$level);;
}

foreach ($arrs as $arr) $arr['level'] =  treegenerate($arr);
```

Comment: It can not work because i return just level how can i know categoryname and id etc. is it important to outside foreach? I tried it but it not worked

Comment: It seems like you transverse the whole $arrs array on each level of your tree multiple times. Each time you make a new treegenerate function call. That drains your memory very fast.

Comment: what should I do? So How to compute levels?